# Pulling data from SQLite, but data is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have a class project where I need to pull data from my SQLite DB and place it into `<table>`.
But every time I reload the page I get this [Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2pBf.png) and I was hoping for some help. I'm new to JavaScript and I need to finish this task in a few hours, I've tried to pull the data into an object and from the object into this line `str += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).Firstname + "</td>"` and still it didn't work.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Customers_Table ', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length, i;
        document.getElementById("tablea").innerHTML = '';
        var str = '';
        str += "<th>FirstName</th>";
        str += "<th>LastName</th>";
        str += "<th>Address</th>";
        str += "<th>City</th>";
        str += "<th>Email</th>";
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            str += "<tr>";
            str += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).Firstname + "</td>";
            str += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).Lastname + "</td>";
            str += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).Address + "</td>";
            str += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).City + "</td>";
            str += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).Email + "</td>";
            str += "</tr>";

            document.getElementById("tablea").innerHTML += str;
            str = '';


        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Think about how to debug it. For example, try `print_r(results);` to see what you get, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering that you have data in results. It should be used as:

```
results.rows.item[i].Firstname
```

NOT

```
results.rows.item(i).Firstname
```

Comment: if im using the [] then it will nor recognize the Firstname column

Comment: it giving me en error but is said "cannot read property 'Firstname' of undefined"

Comment: @YuvalBarzilai, just your result, do `console.log(JSON.strigify(result))`;

Comment: im not using JSON, havent even imported anything

Comment: you dont have to import anything, after `function (tx, results) { console.log(JSON.strigify(result))` to check if the results are coming after your query

Comment: says that JSON.strigify isnt a function in my js file

Comment: just do console.log(result) then

Comment: SQLResultSet {rows: SQLResultSetRowList, rowsAffected: 0}

Comment: looks good since the data is coming, go a level deep and log using console.log(result.rows) or console.log(result.rows.item)

Comment: the  console.log(result.rows) looks good but the .item gets me that ƒ item() { [native code] }

Comment: Okay, then you will probably have to map it to an array that  javascript can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem, the .Firstname and the rest didn't match the column names from the Db table, it was lowercase,look carefully at your code guys!!